# How to find out SSD type for replacement?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd

How can one find out on a 7/24 machine which SSD type (connector) is used? I know that I'll run out of disk space in a certain time and I'd like to order a replacement SSD.

If it's not absolutely necessary I'd prefer not to shutdown and open the computer just to examine which SSD with which connector is used.

How can I find out:

- either exact type of used SSD
- or which connector is used for the SSD

Thank you for your suggestions!

Comment: Check the output of command `sudo hdparm -I /dev/sda` look for the "Model Number" and "Serial Number".

Comment: ATA device, with non-removable media
 Model Number:       SAMSUNG SSD Device                      
 Serial Number:      20160911G1149 (number modified by me to post on forum)       
 Firmware Revision:  Q0111A  
 Media Serial Num:   ü
 Transport:          Serial, ATA8-AST, SATA 1.0a, SATA II Extensions, SATA Rev 2.5, SATA Rev 2.6, SATA Rev 3.0   
 However when I contact Samsung support via phone to ask specific details they say serial no is incorrect. 
 Serial numbers must start with S and have 30 chars.
 
 Question regarding Transport: just buy a replacement SSD with SATA Rev 3.0?